# Recursion Error on overriding the Dictionary __getitem__ magic-method?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, inheritance, magic-methods

I want my **getitem** method to return None, If a key is not available and also add the key with the value 
None. And if the key is available then return the value.

```
>>> class VariableDict(dict):

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            return self[key]
        except KeyError:
            self['key'] = None
            return None


>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> d = VariableDict(d)
>>> d
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> d['k']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#64>", line 1, in <module>
    d['k']
  File "<pyshell#60>", line 5, in __getitem__
    return self['key']
  File "<pyshell#60>", line 5, in __getitem__
    return self['key']
  File "<pyshell#60>", line 5, in __getitem__
    return self['key']
  [Previous line repeated 327 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

What problem am I having here, and are there alternatives to my problem. Please also explain, what's wrong in my code and why this RecursionError occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basiclly because this line:

```
    return self['key']
```

Will invoke `VariableDict`'s `__getitem__` method again, so your method will keep calling itself without stop condition. what you need is to use the superclass `__getitem__` method:

```
super().__getitem__(key)
```

**note**: you are using `'key'` to access a given item, and I think you do not mean that, because `self['key']` will return the same value regardless of the value of `key`.

Comment: Thanks bro, Now I am able to understand the flow of code, and why this recursion error occurs.

Answer (score 4):

The `__getitem__` method is what implements key lookups in a dictionary, so you can't do `self['key']` without it recursing. Instead, you probably want to call the original implementation of `__getitem__` that you're overriding in your class. The usual way to do that is with `super`:

```
    try:
        return super().__getitem__('key')
    except KeyError:
        ...
```

There may be other issues with your code though. You're taking an argument named `key`, but you're not actually using it in your code. Instead you're using the string `'key'` as your key to lookup and set in the dictionary. Probably you want to be using `key` instead of `'key'` with quotation marks.

There's also a better way to give a default value if a value is not found in a dictionary. It's not very well documented, but Python dictionaries can have a `__missing__` method defined, which, if it exists, will be called any time a key lookup fails. The returned value from the method will be the result of the lookup, and you can also modify the dictionary if you want. So a better way to implement your class might be:

```
class VariableDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        self[key] = None            # note, I'm using key instead of 'key' here!
        return None
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I will replace 'key' wth key immediately.

Comment: Yes, implementing __missing__ is the better way. Thanks alot bro.

Comment: I wish I could give you 100 upvotes :)